# Ajax not being called by select

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi I have a select box that when it is changed I want the value in a database to be updated via Ajax. Using the console I can see that my saveedit2.php file is not being called.

Select Box

```
    <form><select id="workingpattern">
    <?php
              if(isset($workingpatterns) && !empty($workingpatterns)){
              foreach($workingpatterns as $k4=>$v4) {
              ?> 

    <option value="<?php echo $workingpatterns[$k4]["workingpatternid"]; ?>"> 
<?php echo $workingpatterns[$k4]["text"]; ?></option>
    <?php }}?>
    </select></form>
```

Ajax:

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#workingpattern').change(function(){
    var e = document.getElementById("workingpattern");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    $.ajax({
        url: "saveedit2.php",
        type: "post",
        data: value,
        success: function(data) {

           console.log(data);
        }});

});

</script>
```

SaveEdit2.php

```
<?php
require_once("connect_db.php");

$value=$_POST['value'];

$sql = "UPDATE employmenthistory SET workingpatternid = '$value' WHERE employmenthistoryid=1";
$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $sql) or die(mysqli_error ($dbc));
?>
```

Comment: Firstly you have a name and not an ID. It is document.getElementById so change name to ID

Comment: Thanks. Done that now but still not being called.

Comment: please do the minimum of debuging before to ask a question. that means looking at every variable to see if the contains the expected values and writing in the question theses values. e.g. display the content of `e` and `value` before the AJAX call

Comment: Did you include jQuery in the head? are there errors in the console?

Comment: I've tried to send the value of value to the console log but it is not appearing so presumably the whole function is not being called. Jquery is called in the head and other ajax calls are working on the page it is only the one dealing with this select box which is not functioning.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues that I see. First, I would use 'this' to get the element and use jQuery to get the value since you are using it already. Secondly, you need a name for the value in the data set:

```
$('#workingpattern').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "saveedit2.php",
        type: "post",
        data: 'value='+value,
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and the function still does not get called and still cant get it to throw an error anywhere.

Comment: Add console.log outputs all over to see where it is stopping. Does it get inside the change function? If so, try setting a fail function to see if maybe that is returning incorrectly. You may have the wrong url path, returning the wrong data back or something else.

Comment: nothing is coming up in the console at all -  I dont think the function is getting called. Do I need to put an onChange or onBlur event handler on? I thought that .change would do it without the need for those.

Comment: .change will do it, but are you creating the event handler before the select is created? Meaning is it dynamic? https://jsfiddle.net/577g6rd7/ works. If you are creating it dynamically, look at jQuery http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Ajax

```
$('#workingpattern').change(function(){
    var value = $("#workingpattern").val();

            $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              url: "./saveedit2.php",
              data: {'value':value},
              success: function(data){
                  if(data['result']=="ok")       
                       alert("Done");
                  else
                      alert("Error");
              }
            });
```

SaveEdit2.php

```
<?php
require_once("connect_db.php");
$ajax_result = "error";
$value=$_POST['value'];

$sql = "UPDATE employmenthistory SET workingpatternid = '$value' WHERE employmenthistoryid=1";
$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $sql) or die(mysqli_error ($dbc));
if($result)
$ajax_result = "ok";

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$ajax_result));

?>
```